# Doxygen does not document variables after variable with attribute

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a .c file where several variables are declared. One of them has the attribute `__align(4)`, i.e. the declaration is `__align(4) static uint32_t myVar;`

When I create the doxygen doc for this source file it only lists the variables which are declared prior to `__align(4) static uint32_t myVar;` (`myVar` is also not included in the doc).

Example:

```
uint32_t var1;                     //documented by doxygen
static uint32_t var2;              //documented by doxygen
__align(4) static uint32_t myVar;  //NOT documented by doxygen
uint32_t var4;                     //NOT documented by doxygen
```

I suspect that doxygen sees that `__align()` is actually a function and stops looking for variable declarations afterwards.

How do I get doxygen to list all my declared variables? A "hacky" solution would be to declare the aligned variable at the bottom of my variable section but the aligned variable would still not be included in the doc.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Greetings

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are the settings in your doxygen configuration file different from the default settings (i.e. `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of points in this question that need attention.

- there is no documentation at all in the example, so we either need the setting `EXTRAC_ALL=YES` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all) or document the variables
- a number of variables are `static`, this implies that we also need the setting `EXTRACT_STATIC=YES` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_static)
- the declaration of `myVar` has the non-standard attribute `__align` and this has to be handled in a similar way as the attribute `__attribute__`, see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) so:

  - `PREDEFINED = __align(x)=`
  - `MACRO_EXPANSION = YES`

So the complete `Doxyfile` can look like:

```
EXTRACT_STATIC=YES
PREDEFINED = __align(x)=
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
```

and the source code:

```
/// \file

/** some docu */
uint32_t var1;                     //documented by doxygen
/** some docu */
static uint32_t var2;              //documented by doxygen
/** some docu */
__align(4) static uint32_t myVar;  //NOT documented by doxygen
/** some docu */
uint32_t var4;                     //NOT documented by doxygen
```

and all is documented as expected.

Comment: Thank you! :) I was using example variables since I can't post our code here. Yes, all variables have a doxygen comment which I forgot to add in my example.
Adding your suggested options to the doxyfile fixed it, thanks alot!